# Exit from Command prompt after running r script

Tags: r, batch-file

I am running one R script through command prompt (CMD window) but CMD window staying open after executing all batch command. I want to close it (CMD window) after executing R Script.

```
@ECHO OFF
START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\ABCD\" & Rscript working.r & exit
```

I am running above code for it but last commands `exit` doesn't work for me.

Did I miss something on the above code?

Comment: You should consider using the /D option of the START command to set the working directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- You only enclosed `cd C:\ABCD` in `"`; you have to double-quote the whole sequence of commands.
- Use the `&&` operator, so that the script will fail if path `C:\ABCD` doesn't exist.

**`cmd /k` option** (run, and **k**eep the cmd open):

```bat
start cmd.exe /k "cd /d C:\ABCD\ && Rscript working.r"
```

**`cmd /c` option** (run, then **c**lose the cmd window):

```bat
start cmd.exe /c "cd /d C:\ABCD\ && Rscript working.r"
```

The `cd`'s `/d` option is used to change drive (if that's needed) in addition to the folder.

Reference: [`CMD.exe` on SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Meaning of the Windows command processor option `/k`

The Windows command processor option `/K` is for running a command line and then **k**eeps running the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` for interactive use by a user or just seeing the output of the executed command line.

The option `/C` is for running a command line and then the Windows command processor **c**loses itself which means the console window with the output is closed too.

That is explained by the usage help of `cmd.exe` which can be read by opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) and running `cmd /?`. There is also the Microsoft documentation page for [cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) explaining these two options.

### 2. Meaning of the Windows command processor operator `&`

There is [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) explaining in full details the unconditional command operator `&` as well as the conditional command operators `&&` and `||` on being recognized by the Windows command processor outside a double quoted argument string.

The unconditional command operator `&` is for specifying multiple commands on one command line to execute one after the other by `cmd.exe` independent on success or failure of the previous executed command.

So the command line

```
START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\ABCD\" & Rscript working.r & exit
```

is interpreted by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file as it would be written in the batch file:

```
START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\ABCD\"
Rscript working.r
exit
```

The goal of the batch file is to change the current directory to `C:\ABCD\`, run `Rscript.exe` with the argument `working.r` to process this R script in the directory `C:\ABCD\` and keep the console window opened for viewing the output while the console window opened on starting the batch file should be closed automatically after starting `Rscript.exe`. But the used command line does something completely different as explained in full details in chapter 5 below.

### 3. Solutions to run R script `working.r` in `C:\ABCD`

The goal to run R script `working.r` in directory `C:\ABCD` with keeping the console window opened with the output of the R script could be achieved with:

```
@echo off
title Run R script working.r
cd /D "C:\ABCD\"
if not errorlevel 1 Rscript.exe working.r
pause
```

These command lines do following:

1. The **CMD** internal command **ECHO** is used to turn off command echo mode which is enabled by default on execution of a batch file resulting in displaying a command line to execute after parsing and processing it immediately before execution.
   `@` at beginning of this line results in not printing this first command line of the batch file to the console window after processing and before executing it.
2. The **CMD** internal command **CD** changes the current directory for the running Windows command process to the specified directory with using option `/D` to change also the current drive if that is necessary too.
   That works for all directory paths with a drive letter and a colon at the beginning, but not for a UNC path starting with `\\ServerName\ShareName\` because of `cmd.exe` does not permit by default making a directory accessed with a UNC path the current directory for compatibility with executables not supporting such a directory path as current directory.
3. If the execution of command **CD** was successful indicated with exit value `0`, the Windows command processor searches for a file with name `Rscript.exe` in current directory and next in the directories listed in environment variable `PATH` using the file extensions listed in environment variable `PATHEXT` and if that file is really found, runs `Rscript.exe` using its fully qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) with passing `working.r` as argument to the executable.
   The search for `Rscript.exe` and its execution is not done on **CD** exits with value 1 indicating an error, for example if the directory `C:\ABCD` was deleted in the meantime. **CD** outputs in this case an error message to handle **STDERR** (standard error) which can be seen in the console window.
4. The command **PAUSE** halts processing of the batch file until the user presses any key so that all output written to the console window can be viewed by the user even on having started the execution of the batch file by double clicking on it in *Windows File Explorer*.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `title /?`

See also:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

There are also multiple other solutions possible.

A shorter version of above:

```
@echo off
title Run R script working.r
cd /D "C:\ABCD\" && Rscript.exe working.r
pause
```

Another single line solution starting one more command processor:

```
@start "Run R script working.r" /D "C:\ABCD" %ComSpec% /D /K Rscript.exe working.r
```

This single command line results in

- starting the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` using its fully qualified file name as defined by the **system** environment variable `ComSpec`
- with option `/D` to ignore the `AutoRun` command in Windows registry if existing at all and
- with option `/K` as explained in chapter 1
- as separate task in a new console window with the window title `Run R script working.r` and
- with `C:\ABCD` as current directory for the started `cmd.exe` which has to
- search for file `Rscript.exe` and if found execute it with R script file name `working.r` as first and only argument with current directory `C:\ABCD` as defined for `cmd.exe`.

For help on command **START** run in a command prompt window `start /?`.

One more single line solution is:

```
@start "Run R script working.r" /D "C:\ABCD" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K Rscript.exe working.r
```

This is the same as the single command line version above with just the small difference that `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` is used instead of `%ComSpec%` which in fact is defined by default with exactly that string as **system** environment variable.

Last but definitely not least can be used also the single command line:

```
@start "Run R script working.r" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /S /K "cd /D "C:\ABCD" && Rscript.exe working.r"
```

This solution becomes a nightmare if the directory path of file `working.r` contains itself the character `&` as in this case the ampersand in directory path must be escaped with `^` left to `&` as the command line is processed by two `cmd.exe`. The `cmd.exe` instance processing the batch file has to interpret all ampersands on the command line as literal characters while `&` in directory path has to be interpreted as literal character and `&&` as conditional **AND** operator by the second `cmd.exe`.

Example of last solution with `&` in directory path:

```
@start "Run R script working.r" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /S /K "cd /D "C:\Temp\Development ^& Test" && Rscript.exe working.r"
```

That is much more complex than:

```
@start "Run R script working.r" /D "C:\Temp\Development & Test" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K Rscript.exe working.r
```

### 4. Alternative solution not using a batch file at all

The execution of an executable like `Rscript.exe` with one or more arguments in a specific directory used as current directory with using the Windows command processor to see the output can be done also using a Windows `.lnk` shortcut file instead of a batch file which has multiple advantages in comparison to the batch file solution.

The shortcut file for executing `Rscript.exe` with `working.r` as argument in directory `C:\ABCD` can be created using the following steps:

1. Browse in *Windows File Explorer* to the directory `System32` in the Windows directory containing `cmd.exe` which is usually `C:\Windows\System32`.
2. Click with secondary (right) pointing device (mouse) button on the file `cmd.exe` to open the context menu and click in submenu **Send to** on the menu item **Desktop (create shortcut)**.
3. Switch to the Windows desktop which has now an additional shortcut file with name `cmd.exe.lnk` whereby the file extension `.lnk` is not visible, just the file name `cmd.exe`.
4. Click with secondary (right) pointing device (mouse) button on `cmd.exe` and click in opened context menu on menu item **Rename** to change the file name for example  to `Run R Script` resulting in shortcut file being rename to `Run R Script.lnk`.
5. Click with secondary (right) pointing device (mouse) button on `Run R Script` and click in opened context menu on last menu item **Properties**.
6. There is opened the **Properties** dialog window with by default selected tab **Shortcut**. On this tab must be modified first the property **Target** on which to append a space character and the string `/D /K Rscript.exe working.r`. Well, even better would be appending after a space the string `/D /K "C:\Full Path\Rscript\Rscript.exe" working.r` so that `cmd.exe` does not need to search for file `Rscript.exe` with using the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT`.
7. There must be next modified the property **Start in** where `C:\ABCD` must be entered as this is the directory which should be the current directory on starting first `cmd.exe` and next `Rscript.exe` because of containing the R script file `working.r`. The **Start in** directory path should be defined always without double quotes even on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` as this string is not processed by the started `cmd.exe` as explained below in chapter 5.

There can be modified also other properties of the shortcut file. There can be defined a **Shortcut key** like <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + R</kbd> to able to execute the R script `working.r` in `C:\ABCD` by pressing this combination of keys independent on which application has currently the input focus. There can be added a **Comment** like `Run R script working.r in C:\ABCD` displayed as tooltip when the pointing device pointer is positioned over the shortcut on Windows desktop. A nice icon can be selected for this shortcut and a different font or font size can be set, etc.

The last step is clicking on button **OK** to save the changed shortcut properties.

The shortcut file can be kept on Windows desktop, but could be moved or copied also into the Windows start menu or pinned on the Windows taskbar as it can be done with any shortcut file.

So with usage of a shortcut file the execution of the R script can be simplified, especially on having a shortcut key defined too. The font and font size can be changed to see output larger than usually in a command prompt window. A nice icon could be selected displayed in the Windows taskbar while the R script is running, etc.

### 5. How is the batch file processed as posted in the question?

The batch file as posted in the question is most likely executed by double clicking on it. For that reason `explorer.exe` is most likely the first executable processing the batch file.

#### 5.1 Processing of the batch file by `explorer.exe`

A batch file with file extension `.bat` or `.cmd` is a text file and does not contain itself CPU instructions. Therefore the *Windows File Explorer* has to find out first what to do with the double clicked batch file. So it searches in the Windows registry under various keys how to open a file with file extension `.bat` or `.cmd` depending on which file extension the batch file has.

1. The *Windows File Explorer* finds the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat` with the default string `batfile` of type `REG_SZ`.
2. There is next looked for registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command` with the default string `"%1" %*` of type `REG_SZ`.
   Batch files are registered different to other file extensions. There is usually configured for the Windows shell command **open** of a file extension the fully qualified file name of the executable to use with `%1` as placeholder for the fully qualified name of the double clicked file enclosed in double quotes.
   Example for `.txt` file extension: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt` has the default string `txtfile` and referencing therefore `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command` with the default string `%SystemRoot%\system32\notepad.exe %1` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` instead of `REG_SZ` as containing an environment variable reference.

The above sequence of registry accesses is extremely simplified as otherwise it would be really too long to list all registry accesses made by `explorer.exe` to find out what to do with the double clicked batch file.

There is called finally by `explorer.exe` the Windows library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw). This function has multiple parameters and it is really worth for any programmer working on Windows to read the documentation of this function and of the structure [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow).

Most of the properties of a shortcut file just define how `CreateProcess` is called by `explorer.exe` with which data set in the structure `STARTUPINFO`.

Most of the options supported by the **CMD** internal command **START** just define the data to pass to `CreateProcess` by `cmd.exe`.

Some examples:

- Function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` is a long pointer to a string with the current directory to set for the process to create. If this pointer is a null pointer, `CreateProcess` uses the current directory of the process which creates the new process. Otherwise the specified string is interpreted as path of the current directory for the new process. The shortcut property **Start in** is the string passed by `explorer.exe` using `lpCurrentDirectory` to function `CreateProcess`. The string after option `/D` of command **START** of **CMD** is the string passed without the double quotes by `cmd.exe` using `lpCurrentDirectory` to function `CreateProcess`.
- The structure `STARTUPINFO` has the element `dwFlags` which is a bitfield with one bit being `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`. `cmd.exe` runs a Windows console application like `Rscript.exe` specified in a batch file by default using `CreateProcess` with this bit in `dwFlags` in `STARTUPINFO` passed with a pointer to `CreateProcess` with the value `0`. So no new console window is opened on running `Rscript.exe`. But on using command **START** the flag `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` has always the value `1` on `CreateProcess` being called by `cmd.exe` to run the application always with a new window. `explorer.exe` sets always `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`.
- The structure `STARTUPINFO` has the elements `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput` and `hStdError` which are defined by `cmd.exe` depending on a console application like `Rscript` should use the standard input, standard output and standard error streams of `cmd.exe` or new streams should be created by `CreateProcess` for this application which is one more difference between running `Rscript.exe` directly from within a batch file or using the command **START**.

Every Windows executable capable of running one more Windows executable calls `CreateProcss` in the Windows kernel library `kernel32.dll`. So it is really useful for every Windows programmer to have knowledge about this function, which data can be passed to it and how it works.

So finally `explorer.exe` uses `CreateProcess` to run, for example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\RunRscript.bat" "
```

A new console window is opened by `CreateProcess` as requested by `explorer.exe` by using by default the options as stored under registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` on starting `cmd.exe` with option `/c` to process the double clicked batch file and then close itself.

#### 5.2 Processing of the batch file by `cmd.exe`

The Windows command processor first parses the argument strings passed to it by `explorer.exe` which are `/c` and a command line to execute enclosed in `"` whereby the first and the last `"` are removed to have finally just the fully qualified file name of the batch file enclosed in double quotes.

For that reason the Windows command processor opens the batch file, reads the first line, parses it, finds out that no more line must be read, closes the batch file and executes the first command line which is `@ECHO OFF` resulting in turning off the command echo mode.

Next `cmd.exe` opens the batch file again, sets the file pointer to beginning of second line, reads that line, parses it, finds out that no more line must be read, closes the batch file and splits up internally the command line

```
START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\ABCD\" & Rscript working.r & exit
```

to the following commands added to its internal command queue:

```
START cmd.exe /k "cd C:\ABCD\"
Rscript working.r
exit
```

So there are three commands to execute next independent on the execution results of each previous command.

#### 5.2.1 Starting one more `cmd.exe` as separate task

The first command to execute is the internal command **START**. So `cmd.exe` parses the arguments as described for the command **START**.

There is defined neither a window title string nor any other **START** specific option. So the first argument `cmd.exe` is the application name to pass to `CreateProcess`. But the path is missing and for that reason `cmd.exe` processing the batch file has to search first for this file.

There is most likely no `cmd.exe` in current directory. So the first folder path from the environment variable `PATH`  is used next to search for `cmd.exe`. The Windows default is `%SystemRoot%\System32` as first folder path of `PATH` and this directory contains indeed `cmd.exe`. So the search for the fully qualified file name of `cmd.exe` could be finished quickly and the application name string passed to function `CreateProcess` by using the function parameter `lpApplicationName` is defined completely.

All other arguments after `cmd.exe` are to pass to `CreateProcess` as string with using the pointer `lpCommandLine`.

Therefore `cmd.exe` processing the batch file now calls `CreateProcess` with `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` as application name, the string `/k "cd C:\ABCD\"` as command line, a null pointer for the current directory, a null pointer for the environment, etc. to start one more `cmd.exe` running parallel to current `cmd.exe` process with its own console window and its own standard input, standard output and standard error streams.

The `cmd.exe` process processing the batch file gets back from `CreateProcess` a nonzero value for successful creation of the process. So it continues with the next command in its internal command queue while the started `cmd.exe` is running now parallel.

#### 5.2.2 Calling `Rscript` with the argument `working.r`

The next command in internal command queue of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file is:

```
Rscript working.r
```

`Rscript` is not an internal command of **CMD**. So this string is interpreted as executable or script file name which must be first found at all as specified with just the file name without full path and without file extension. Therefore `cmd.exe` uses again the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` to find a program/script file with that name and finds most likely indeed `Rscript.exe` in right directory.

There is to call again `CreateProcess`, but this time the application name is `Rscript.exe` with its full path, the command line is the string `working.r`, `lpEnvironment` is again a null pointer (as used always with a null pointer by `cmd.exe`), `lpCurrentDirectory` is a null pointer, etc. The difference is that this time `Rscript.exe` is not started as separate task with its own window, standard streams, etc. `Rscript` is **called** by `cmd.exe`.

Therefore `Rscript.exe` runs now and processes the command line. If the file `working.r` is found at all, cannot be determined by the provided information in the question. If the R script file is in same directory as the batch file, then the inheritance of the current working directory as defined by `explorer.exe` starting `cmd.exe` to process the batch file and `cmd.exe` on starting `Rscript.exe` to process the R script file results in a by chance working execution of the R script file now. Otherwise `Rscript.exe` exits most likely with an error as the file `working.r` could not be found in the current directory.

After `Rscript.exe` finished without or with execution of `working.r`, the Windows command processor instance processing the batch file continues with its internal command queue.

#### 5.2.3 Exiting the Windows command processor

The remaining command in the internal command queue is `exit` which is an internal command of **CMD**. It instructs to immediately exit itself without further processing the batch file. So `cmd.exe` processing the batch file closes itself now.

### 5.3 Processing of second started `cmd.exe`

The `cmd.exe` process started by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file processes first its arguments.

There is the option `/k` to instruct `cmd.exe` to execute the command line specified with the next argument(s) and then to keep running.

The command line to execute is `cd C:\ABCD\` whereby **CD** is recognized as internal command of **CMD** and `C:\ABCD\` as the directory path.

The command **CD** is executed and if the current drive is the drive `C:`, the current directory is changed now for the second `cmd.exe` process while the first `cmd.exe` process is searching parallel for `Rscript.exe`.

There is nothing more to do for second `cmd.exe`, but it keeps running for user interactions.

The console window of second `cmd.exe` remains open with a prompt indicating `C:\ABCD` as current directory and waiting for user input.